# nmcli centos with wrong general.type

Tags: wifi, nmcli

I am trying to configure a centos machine to use wifi via a usb wifi dongle.  I have plugged the thing in and got the drivers working

```
# iwconfig
ra0       Ralink STA  ESSID:""  Nickname:"MT7610U_STA"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   
          RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Link Quality=10/100  Signal level:0 dBm  Noise level:0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

However, nmcli thinks that this is an ethernet connection

```
# nmcli device show ra0
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         ra0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         84:16:F9:1F:6A:92  
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
```

which leads to

```
# nmcli device wifi connect WirelessNetwork ifname ra0
Error: Device 'ra0' is not a Wi-Fi device.
```

How do I fix this?